# Angular Factory never called (Ionic + PouchDB + CouchDB)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm following this tutorial to create a Ionic App that sync data throw PouchDB and CouchDB: http://frontmag.no/artikler/utvikling/offline-data-synchronization-ionic

But the app didn't work 100% with me. The prompt add the doc on my Pouchdb and it's doing the sync with CouchDB.

The problem is on my interface that doesn't show the new TODO.
So debugging I found out that bellow `console.log("change");` inside `app.factory('PouchDBListener', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {` is never called.

```
// Ionic Starter App
var localDB = new PouchDB("todos");
var remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://192.168.0.16:5984/todos");

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

  localDB.sync(remoteDB, {live: true, retry: true});

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});


// For more information about $broadcast and factories, you can check AngularJS docs.

app.factory('PouchDBListener', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  localDB.changes({
    continuous: true,
    onChange: function(change) {

      console.log("change");

      if (!change.deleted) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          localDB.get(change.id, function(err, doc) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
              if (err) console.log(err);
              $rootScope.$broadcast('add', doc);
            })
          });
        })
      } else {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('delete', change.id);
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return true;
}]);


app.controller("TodoController", function($scope, $ionicPopup, PouchDBListener) {
  $scope.todos = [
    {
      "title": "Item 1",
      "done": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Item 2",
      "done": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Item 3",
      "done": false
    }
  ];

  $scope.create = function() {
    $ionicPopup.prompt({
      title: 'Enter a new TODO',
      inputType: 'text'
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      if(result) {

        //console.log("I'm here 1");  

        if($scope.hasOwnProperty("todos") !== true) {
          //console.log("I'm here 2");
          $scope.todos = [];
          //console.log("I'm here 3");
        }

        //console.log("I'm here 4");

        localDB.post({title: result, done: false}).then(function(result) {
          //console.log("I'm here 5");
          return localDB.get(result.id);
        }).then(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        });

        //console.log("I'm here 6");

      } else {
        console.log("Action cancelled.");
      }
    });
  }

  $scope.update = function(todo) {
    localDB.put({
      _id: todo._id,
      _rev: todo._rev,
      title: todo.title,
      done: todo.done
    })
    .then(function(result){
      // You can set some action after the item was updated.
    });
  }

  $scope.$on('add', function(event, todo) {
    var add = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(value, key) {
      if (value._id == todo._id) {
        $scope.todos[key] = todo;
        add = false;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (add) {
      $scope.todos.push(todo);
    }
  });

  $scope.$on('delete', function(event, id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.todos.length; i++) {
      if($scope.todos[i]._id === id) {
        $scope.todos.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[image: My result so far.]

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. My PouchDB is maybe on another version. So I did handle the change how it's show on https://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html:

```
localDB.changes({
  continuous: true,
}).on('change',  function(change) {

  console.log("change 2");

  if (!change.deleted) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      localDB.get(change.id, function(err, doc) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          $rootScope.$broadcast('add', doc);
        })
      });
    })
  } else {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('delete', change.id);
    });
  }

}).on('error', function (err) {
  // handle errors
});
```